# Blender VSE keeps freezing every time I try to click on anything

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender 3.0.0 alpha, b/c of Cycles X to render faster, b/c I'm on a time crunch. I've been using the Blender VSE to do my video editing for a school project, but now, I don't know if that was a bad decision or not. I've been looking everywhere for solutions to speed it up, but I don't know what to do. I saw a video from MikeyCal with a solution to combat the problem, but I think it might be too late, as I have too many elements in my video and I don't know if this solution still works for Blender. What he did was to set the video proxy to 50%.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZl1xS9Lmvw&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=10
Here is the video to see what his solution was.
I have a lot of video and sound elements in my edit (blend file) and every time I try clicking on anything, it just freezes and Blender struggles to do anything. Should I just restart and use a different video editor like Davinci Resolve or not?[image: This is what happens every time I try to click on anything in the timeline, or the menu for the strips. I hid everything to try and make it go a bit faster, but that didn't do anything :/]
edit: I also looked at task manager and found that only 31% of RAM was being used and CPU was being used at 41%, then GPU usage was less 5%. I also tried using blender 2.9.2 (stable) but i've encountered the same problem. :/

Comment: Well, to quote from the Blender homepage on experimental builds: "Experimental builds have the latest features and while there might be cool bug fixes too, they are unstable and can mess up your files. It is **not recommended** to use these on production environments." Especially when you're on a time crunch I don't know if it's wise to try to save time on rendering which you waste on troubleshooting, And I might be wrong but I don't think Cycles X speeds up video editing.

Comment: Cycles X is for rendering faster, so I used it to render out the text animations and elements along with the couches and other stuff I modeled and rendered.

Comment: Yes, rendering the animation might be faster, but for putting together existing videos or image sequences it won't be a big difference. Well anyway, experimental builds are often unstable and buggy, so if you're really in a hurry and need reliable software I wouldn't use them.

Comment: I just deleted everything and the timeline is now working flawlessly :( What I'll do is just re-add everything, but this time, I'm using 2.9.2 (stable) or the latest stable version and be more careful to optimize.